# How can I list all files, but only in directories that have no subdirectories?

Tags: linux, files, find

I have a directory tree that I want to search recursively for all files of a certain type (for example all `.jpg`'s), but I only want to list these files if they are at the bottom of a directory tree.

As an example if my tree looks like:

```
                          home
                          root
                   f1     f2     f3
                   f11    f22    f33
                   f111   f222   f333
```

and all folders have `.jpg`'s, I only want to list the `.jpg`'s in `f111`/`f222`/`f333`, and so on, and ignore the ones in the higher up folders.

I know that I can use a find command (like `find . -name "*.jpg"`) to get a listing of all `.jpg`'s in the entire tree, but I'm not sure how to limit it to only the bottom most folders without doing something like `grep`'ing the results to filter for `111`/`222`/`333`'s which isn't really feasible as I have hundreds of folders and I don't know what the last level folders might be named for all of them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

```
find . -type d -links 2 -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} find {} -name \*.jpg
```

The first command lists all directories without any subdirectories (since each subdirectory adds one to the link count, while an empty directory has two). The second invokes `find` manually on each of these results.

Comment: Note that the `-links 2` trick won't work with all filesystems (not with `btrfs` or `nilfs2` or `ntfs` or `vfat` for instance).

Comment: Huh. I had not yet noticed that `btrfs` didn't do the directory-link-count thing.

Answer (score 1):

A POSIX equivalent of [@TomHunt's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241051).

```
find . -type d -links 2 -exec sh -c '
  find "$@" -type f -name "*.jpg"' sh {} +
```

The `-links 2` relies on the property of some file systems that the link count of directories (initially 2 for the entry in their parent and the `.` entry in themselves) increases by one for every subdir (because of the `..` entry in them). Some modern filesystems like `btrfs` or `nilfs` whose structures are radically different don't have such a property though.

With `zsh`, you could do something like:

```
has_subdirs() {
  local l
  l=($REPLY/*(/DNoN[1]))
  (($#l))
}
dirs_without_subdirs=(**/*(DN^+has_subdirs))
jpgs=($^dirs_without_subdirs/*.jpg(ND.))
(($#jpgs)) && printf '%s\n' $jpgs
```